# Can we fail build in jenkins after jfrog xray-scan?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

Is there a way we can fail a build in jenkins after xray scan and  getting an unapproved license violation from jfog xray (No pipeline script)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate your Jenkins (or any CI tool), you can follow [this wiki page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/CI-CD+Integration+with+Xray#CICDIntegrationwithXray-SettingUpXrayCIIntegration).

As can be seen from the link provided, in order to integrate between the CI and Xray a [pipeline job is required](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-ScanningBuildswithJFrogXray) ([declarative](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax#DeclarativePipelineSyntax-ScanningBuildswithJFrogXray) or [scripted](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-ScanningBuildswithJFrogXray)).

I hope this helps and clarifies more.

Answer (score 0):

If the Xray service has been defined with an action under the watch to fail a build upon detecting a vulnerability or a license violation, it will fail the build. Please check, [Creating Xray policies: Automatic actions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Creating+Xray+Policies+and+Rules#CreatingXrayPoliciesandRules-PolicyViolationAutomaticActionsautoactions).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have already defined that action in watch and assigned a policy to fail build if i get unapproved license violation but build wont fail, as jenkins doesn't know of x-ray and violations